# how to require minimum length letters from query to match in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to require that the query be at least 5 matching consecutive characters for matching a particular field. They can be somewhat fuzzy (would be ideal if the longer the sequence is, the fuzzier it can be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I defined n-gram with no min 5 characters in gram. That way it is possible to match with at least 5 characters.

```
PUT teste
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "ngram": {
            "type": "text",
            "analyzer": "shingle_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "shingle_analyzer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "shingle_filter"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "shingle_filter": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 5,
          "max_gram": 8
        }
      }
    }
  }
}    

POST teste/_doc
{
  "name":"example text match fiver terms sequence"
}

GET teste/_search
{
  "query": {
      "match": {
        "name.ngram": "exampl"
      }   
  }
}
```